# Custom layout theme JWPlayer

Tags: jwplayer

Basically, the video is always placed above controlbar, it cannot be used background transparent, I want my layout like the image below, can someone help me?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might find this interesting

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1412123-building-jw-player-skins

There's a picture halfway down which looks like what you've described, take a look! :)

Answer (score 1):

In JW Player 6 (the current version), the controlbar is placed like your "custom" example. In fact, that's the default, and it's very difficult to change it. An example:

http://misterneutron.com/JW6video/

Answer (score 0):

The default JW Player has the controlbar in an 'over' state - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406723-mp4-video-embed